# Selecting specific rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on gps data right now, the position of the animal has been collected if possible every 4 hours. The data looks like this (XY data is not shown here for some reasons):

```
  ID  TIME           POSIXTIME  date_only
1   1 12:00 2005-05-08 12:00:00 2005-05-08
2   2 16:01 2005-05-08 16:01:00 2005-05-08
3   3 20:01 2005-05-08 20:01:00 2005-05-08
4   4  0:01 2005-05-09 00:01:00 2005-05-09
5   5  8:01 2005-05-09 08:01:00 2005-05-09
6   6 12:01 2005-05-09 12:01:00 2005-05-09
7   7 16:02 2005-05-09 16:02:00 2005-05-09
8   8 20:02 2005-05-09 20:02:00 2005-05-09
9   9  0:01 2005-05-10 00:01:00 2005-05-10
10 10  4:00 2005-05-10 04:00:00 2005-05-10
```

I would now like to take only the first locations per day. In most cases, this will be at 0:01 o'clock. However, sometimes it will be 4:01 or even later as there is missing data.
**How can I get only the first locations per day?** They should be included in a new dataframe. I tried it with :

```
tapply(as.numeric(Kandularaw$TIME),list(Kandularaw$date_only),min, na.rm=T)
```

However, this did not work as R takes strange values when TIME is set as numeric.
Is it possible do do it with an ifelse statement? If yes, how would it look like roughly?
I am grateful for every help I can get. Thank you for your efforts.

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you really want a row number as an index into a position record. If you know that these rows are ordered by date-time, and you are getting satisfactory group splits with that second argument to `tapply` (however it was created), then try this:

```
idx <- tapply(1:NROW(Kandularaw), Kandularaw$date_only, "[", 1)
```

If you want records (rows) in that same dataframe then just use:

```
Kandularaw[ idx, ]
```

Comment: Thanks.Actually, I need a dataframe with only those first locations per day

Comment: As I said ... use as an index to get a record. See above.

Comment: Oh, somehow I did not notice that. Thank you very much. This works and  it is exactly what I wanted:)

Comment: Another thing, what does the expression "[" in this case mean? Just want to really understand the command... Thanks a lot

Comment: @JanBlanke `[` is a function in R so you can use it as the function to be applied in the `(t|s|l)apply` family of functions, amongst others. As `[` is treated in a special way by the the parser, you have to quote it. It is basically saying, split the `1:NROW(x)` vector by `date_only` and apply the `[` function to each chunk with extra argument `1`. The `1` refers to the first element of each chunk and is an argument to the `[` function.

Comment: It is just using the function "[". The extraction operation is done either with "[" (mainly used for vectors, data.frames, and matrice, or "[[" (mainly used with lists.) So that is one way to get the first element of each resulting (possibly varying lengths) vector. You probably could have used the `head` function with an argument of 1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this from a simpler point of view. First, ensure that `POSIXTIME` is one of the `"POSIX"` classes. Then order the data by `POSIXTIME`. At this point we can use any of the split-apply-combine idioms to do what you want, making use of the `head()` function. Here I use `aggregate()`:

Using this example data set:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, TIME = structure(c(4L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("00:01:00", "04:00:00", "08:01:00", 
"12:00:00", "12:01:00", "16:01:00", "16:02:00", "20:01:00", "20:02:00"
), class = "factor"), POSIXTIME = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2005/05/08 12:00:00", 
"2005/05/08 16:01:00", "2005/05/08 20:01:00", "2005/05/09 00:01:00", 
"2005/05/09 08:01:00", "2005/05/09 12:01:00", "2005/05/09 16:02:00", 
"2005/05/09 20:02:00", "2005/05/10 00:01:00", "2005/05/10 04:00:00"
), class = "factor"), date_only = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2005/05/08", "2005/05/09", 
"2005/05/10"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "TIME", "POSIXTIME", 
"date_only"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L))
```

First, get `POSIXTIME` and `date_only` in the correct formats:

```
dat <- transform(dat,
                 POSIXTIME = as.POSIXct(POSIXTIME, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"),
                 date_only = as.Date(date_only, format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Next, order by `POSIXTIME`:

```
dato <- with(dat, dat[order(POSIXTIME), ])
```

The final step is to use `aggregate()` to split the data by `date_only` and use `head()` to select the first row:

```
aggregate(dato[,1:3], by = list(date = dato$`date_only`), FUN = head, n = 1)
```

notice I pass the `n` argument of `head()` the value `1`, indicating that it should extract only the first row of each days observations. Because we sorted by datetime and split on date, the first row should be the first observation per day. Do be aware of rounding issues however.

The final step results in:

```
> aggregate(dato[,1:3], by = list(date = dato$`date_only`), FUN = head, n = 1)
        date ID     TIME           POSIXTIME
1 2005-05-08  1 12:00:00 2005-05-08 12:00:00
2 2005-05-09  4 00:01:00 2005-05-09 00:01:00
3 2005-05-10  9 00:01:00 2005-05-10 00:01:00
```

Instead of `dato[,1:3]` refer to whatever columns in your original data set contain the variables (locations?) you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Also this approach worked for me. Its interesting how you can solve the problem on different ways.